# PEGjs grammar star (*) not matching as expected

Tags: parsing, peg, ll-grammar, pegjs

I have this lexeme:

```
a().length()
```

And this PEGjs grammar:

```
start = func_call

func_call = header "(" ")"

header = "a" suffix*

suffix = "(" ")" ("." "length")
```

In the grammar, I'm parsing a function call. This currently parses, as you can [try online in the PEGjs playground](https://pegjs.org/online).

> Input parsed successfully.

However, if I add an asterisk to the end of the suffix production, like so:

```
suffix = "(" ")" ("." "length")*
```

Then the input fails to parse:

> Line 1, column 13: Expected "(" or "." but end of input found.

I don't understand why. From [the documentation](https://pegjs.org/documentation):

> *expression ** Match zero or more repetitions of the expression and return their match results in an array. The matching is greedy

This should be a greedy match of `"." "length"` which should match one time. But instead it fails to match at all. Is this related to the nested use of `*` in `header`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` matches **zero** or more repetitions of its operand, as you say.

So when you write

```
suffix = "(" ")" ("." "length")*
```

You are saying that a suffix is `()` followed by **zero** or more repetitions of `.length`. Thus it could be `()`, which has zero repetitions.

Thus, `suffix*` (in `header`) can match `().length()` as two  repetitions of `suffix`, first `().length`, and then `()`. That would be the greedy match, which is PEG's *modus operandi*.

But after that, there is no `()` left to be matched by `func_call`. Hence the parse error.